# Audio to play on background of website only if it is between 1pm and 2pm

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm working on a website for a friend, and having a few problems with adding audio.

So the idea is that the audio sample only plays (once, not looped, but plays again if refreshed) when the website is visited between 1pm and 2pm.

This is the code I have so far, where am I going wrong ?

```
    <audio id="whiterose" preload="auto">
<source src="//sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.mp3" /> 
<source src="//sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.ogg" />
</audio>


<script>

//AUDIO - only between 13 - 14

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

var x = document.getElementById("whiterose"); 

//if it is between 13 - 14
if (13 <= currentTime && currentTime < 14) 
{
x.play();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

current time 13 is the time between 1 and 2 pm so only check your time with 13

```
if(currentTime == 13){
    x.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add http: in the source to make sure that browser is aware of the protocol. Also, correct your condition in the if statement.

```
<audio id="whiterose" preload="auto">
<source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/> 
<source src="http://sarahboulton.co.uk/audio/white-rose.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>


<script>

//AUDIO - only between 13 - 14

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

var x = document.getElementById("whiterose"); 

//if it is between 13 - 14
if (currentTime === 13) 
{
    x.play();
}

</script>
```